# Autowired MockMvc is null with JUnit 5 and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a class test which send me an error when I run the test.
I followed several threads and I have the right import "import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test"
So I don't understand why it sends me this error :

> Cannot invoke "org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder)" because "this.mockMvc" is null

My code :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(TestController.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CreateMessageProvider createMessageProvider;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/test"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("OK"));
    }
}
```

Gradle config :

```
        mockitoCoreVersion = '4.6.1'
        mockitoJunitJupiterVersion = '4.6.1'
        springBootTestVersion = '2.7.2'
        springTestVersion = '5.3.22'

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:$springBootTestVersion"
    testImplementation "org.springframework:spring-test:$springTestVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:$mockitoJunitJupiterVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoCoreVersion"
```

EDIT : I found the solution. My gradle file didn't have this dependency :

```
testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.2"
```

Comment: Try adding `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` class level annotation

Comment: @Tim I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CreateMessageProvider createMessageProvider;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/test"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("OK"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile I get ```Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}```

Answer (score 0):

Use these annotations :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})
```